# MS Access SQL strange IIF in query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I found: `& ""=""` in query and I don't know what that means

```
IIf(((Field1 Like '*POU*' Or Filed1 Like '*MLS*') And Field2 & ""="") 
Or (Field1 & ""="" And Field2 & ""=""),"TRUE","FALSE") AS POU
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a bit more context for `& ""=""` ...

```sql
Field2 & ""=""
```

That expression asks the db engine to concatenate an empty string (`""`) to the value of *Field2* and check whether the concatenated result is equal to an empty string.

Whenever the starting value of *Field2* is either Null or an empty string, `Field2 & ""` will be an empty string ... so the equality comparison will be True.

If *Field2* contains anything other than Null or an empty string, `Field2 & ""` will not be an empty string ... so the comparison will be False.

In other words, `Field2 & ""=""` is a more concise way to express this logic ...

```sql
Field2 Is Null OR Field2 = ""
```